# React native app crashing without any errors - adb logs given below

Tags: java, android, reactjs, flutter, react-native

React app crashes without any errors,
previous same app worked fine now it is crashing without any errors so I took logs from adb logs and shared them below.

whenever I open the app it is crashing build is getting success

here I gave build.gradle

```
   ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "29.0.2"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 33
        targetSdkVersion = 33
    }
```

dependencies added here :  app/build.gradle

```
implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
//noinspection GradleDynamicVersion
def REACT_NATIVE_VERSION = new File(['node', '--
print',"JSON.parse(require('fs').readFileSync(require.resolve('react-native/package.json'), 'utf-8')).version"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim())

implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:" + REACT_NATIVE_VERSION;  // From node_modules
// implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.8.0'
// implementation ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:16.+') { force = true; }
// implementation "com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd";
// implementation "com.google.android.gms.ads.interstitial.InterstitialAd";
// implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.1'
implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.7.1';
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.9.0';


implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:17.0.0";
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.1.0";
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-stats:17.0.0";
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:17.0.0";
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.8.0";




implementation "androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0";

debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
  exclude group:'com.facebook.fbjni'
}

debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-network-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
    exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
    exclude group:'com.squareup.okhttp3', module:'okhttp'
}

debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-fresco-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
    exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
}
 implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
 implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"
 implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+";  // From node_modules

 implementation project(':react-native-vector-icons')
 
//  implementation project(':RNAdMob')
 implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'


if (enableHermes) {
    def hermesPath = "../../node_modules/hermes-engine/android/";
    debugImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-debug.aar")
    releaseImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
} else {
    implementation jscFlavor
}
```

adblogs:

```
08-01 11:27:12.844   551   581 W WindowManager:         at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:46)
08-01 11:27:12.941   551  1956 I ActivityManager: Process com.whatsappstatusdownload2save (pid 5184) has died: prcp TOP
08-01 11:27:13.139   551   581 W WindowManager: Failed to deliver inset control state change to w=Window{46dc90e u0 com.whatsappstatusdownload2save/com.whatsappstatusdownload2save.MainActivity EXITING}
08-01 11:27:13.139   551   581 W WindowManager: android.os.DeadObjectException
08-01 11:27:13.139   551   581 W WindowManager:         at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
08-01 11:27:13.139   551   581 W WindowManager:         at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(BinderProxy.java:584)
08-01 11:27:13.139   551   581 W WindowManager:         at android.view.IWindow$Stub$Proxy.insetsControlChanged(IWindow.java:479)
08-01 11:27:13.139   551   581 W WindowManager:         at com.android.server.wm.WindowState.notifyInsetsControlChanged(WindowState.java:3794)
08-01 11:27:13.139   551   581 W WindowManager:         at com.android.server.wm.InsetsStateController.lambda$notifyPendingInsetsControlChanged$3(InsetsStateController.java:343)
08-01 11:27:13.139   551   581 W WindowManager:         at com.android.server.wm.InsetsStateController.$r8$lambda$8yykPRG1GyNq_J17QvL9d5xANMc(InsetsStateController.java:0)
08-01 11:27:13.139   551   581 W WindowManager:         at com.android.server.wm.InsetsStateController$$ExternalSyntheticLambda2.run(R8$$SyntheticClass:0)
08-01 11:27:13.139   551   581 W WindowManager:         at com.android.server.wm.WindowAnimator.executeAfterPrepareSurfacesRunnables(WindowAnimator.java:294)
08-01 11:27:13.139   551   581 W WindowManager:         at com.android.server.wm.RootWindowContainer.performSurfacePlacementNoTrace(RootWindowContainer.java:811)
08-01 11:27:13.139   551   581 W WindowManager:         at com.android.server.wm.RootWindowContainer.performSurfacePlacement(RootWindowContainer.java:756)
08-01 11:27:13.139   551   581 W WindowManager:         at com.android.server.wm.WindowSurfacePlacer.performSurfacePlacementLoop(WindowSurfacePlacer.java:177)
08-01 11:27:13.139   551   581 W WindowManager:         at com.android.server.wm.WindowSurfacePlacer.performSurfacePlacement(WindowSurfacePlacer.java:126)
08-01 11:27:13.139   551   581 W WindowManager:         at com.android.server.wm.WindowSurfacePlacer.performSurfacePlacement(WindowSurfacePlacer.java:115)
08-01 11:27:13.139   551   581 W WindowManager:         at com.android.server.wm.WindowSurfacePlacer$Traverser.run(WindowSurfacePlacer.java:57)
08-01 11:27:13.139   551   581 W WindowManager:         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:958)
08-01 11:27:13.139   551   581 W WindowManager:         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-01 11:27:13.139   551   581 W WindowManager:         at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205)
08-01 11:27:13.139   551   581 W WindowManager:         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294)
08-01 11:27:13.139   551   581 W WindowManager:         at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
08-01 11:27:13.139   551   581 W WindowManager:         at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:46)
08-01 11:27:13.204   551   577 V WindowManager:     info={id=10 t=CLOSE f=0x10 trk=0 r=[0@Point(0, 0)] c=[{WCT{RemoteToken{cc078bb Task{2dca30 #1 type=home}}} m=TO_FRONT f=SHOW_WALLPAPER|MOVE_TO_TOP leash=Surface(name=Task=1)/@0xc7615e4 sb=Rect(0, 0 - 1440, 3120) eb=Rect(0, 0 - 1440, 3120) d=0},{WCT{RemoteToken{480c6b5 Task{b8692d1 #54 type=standard A=10184:com.whatsappstatusdownload2save}}} m=CLOSE f=NONE leash=Surface(name=Task=54)/@0x1237e5f sb=Rect(0, 0 - 1440, 3120) eb=Rect(0, 0 - 1440, 3120) d=0},{null m=TO_FRONT f=IS_WALLPAPER leash=Surface(name=WallpaperWindowToken{2f86cdf token=android.os.Binder@3924f7e})/@0x5edfe53 sb=Rect(0, 0 - 1440, 3120) eb=Rect(0, 0 - 1440, 3120) d=0}]}
08-01 11:27:13.499   551  1956 W WindowManager: Exception thrown during dispatchAppVisibility Window{46dc90e u0 com.whatsappstatusdownload2save/com.whatsappstatusdownload2save.MainActivity EXITING}
08-01 11:27:13.499   551  1956 W WindowManager: android.os.DeadObjectException
08-01 11:27:13.499   551  1956 W WindowManager:         at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
08-01 11:27:13.499   551  1956 W WindowManager:         at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(BinderProxy.java:584)
08-01 11:27:13.499   551  1956 W WindowManager:         at android.view.IWindow$Stub$Proxy.dispatchAppVisibility(IWindow.java:546)
08-01 11:27:13.499   551  1956 W WindowManager:         at com.android.server.wm.WindowState.sendAppVisibilityToClients(WindowState.java:3271)
08-01 11:27:13.499   551  1956 W WindowManager:         at com.android.server.wm.WindowContainer.sendAppVisibilityToClients(WindowContainer.java:1221)
08-01 11:27:13.499   551  1956 W WindowManager:         at com.android.server.wm.WindowToken.setClientVisible(WindowToken.java:409)
08-01 11:27:13.499   551  1956 W WindowManager:         at com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.setClientVisible(ActivityRecord.java:6946)
08-01 11:27:13.499   551  1956 W WindowManager:         at com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.postApplyAnimation(ActivityRecord.java:5637)
08-01 11:27:13.499   551  1956 W WindowManager:         at com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.commitVisibility(ActivityRecord.java:5580)
08-01 11:27:13.499   551  1956 W WindowManager:         at com.android.server.wm.Transition.finishTransition(Transition.java:1143)
08-01 11:27:13.499   551  1956 W WindowManager:         at com.android.server.wm.TransitionController.finishTransition(TransitionController.java:859)
08-01 11:27:13.499   551  1956 W WindowManager:         at com.android.server.wm.WindowOrganizerController.finishTransition(WindowOrganizerController.java:396)
08-01 11:27:13.499   551  1956 W WindowManager:         at android.window.IWindowOrganizerController$Stub.onTransact(IWindowOrganizerController.java:286)
08-01 11:27:13.499   551  1956 W WindowManager:         at com.android.server.wm.WindowOrganizerController.onTransact(WindowOrganizerController.java:181)
08-01 11:27:13.499   551  1956 W WindowManager:         at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1344)
08-01 11:27:13.499   551  1956 W WindowManager:         at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1275)
08-01 11:27:13.646   551  5261 W ActivityManager: Ignoring remove of inactive process: ProcessRecord{a994481 0:com.whatsappstatusdownload2save/u0a184}
```

gradle wrapper properties:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5-all.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
```